# understanding callback and return functions in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am new to programming and trying to understand callback functions and functions in general. This program compares 2 values passed in the functions(using callback) and return true/false to us.

```
function func1(param1, callback) {
    return callback(param1);
}

function func2(param2) {
    return function(param3) {
        return param3 > param2;
     }
}

var functionResult = func1(10, func2(9)); 
console.log(functionResult);       // prints - true
```

Question - In this program above, how does the return function inside the func2 function, return the value directly to us, without being invoked? I thought in this line `var functionResult = func1(10, func2(9));` func2(9) will return only the text

```
function(param3) {
        return param3 > param2;
     }
```

and then I would have to invoke it again with ().

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do JavaScript closures work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how does the return function inside the func2 function, return the value directly to us, without being invoked?

It is invoked. `func1` invokes it here:

```
callback(param1)
```

> func2(9) will return only the text ...

That's not text, that's actually a function (object). It is passed to `func1` which in turn calls it and returns its return value.

> and then I would have to invoke it again with ().

Yes, which, again, is what `func1` does:

```
callback(param1)
```

---

Lets take things apart:

```
 var functionResult = func1(10, func2(9));
```

is the same as

```
var func2Result = func2(9);
var functionResult = func1(10, func2Result);
```

Since we know what `func1` does, we can replace the call to it with it's implementation. `10` is passed as `param1` and `func2Result` is passed as `callback`, so the code becomes:

```
var func2Result = func2(9);
var functionResult = func2Result(10); // callback(param1);
```

Now you should be able to see that the return value of `func2` is actually called.

Comment: thanks, the taking things apart part really made it clear to me

Comment: I just realized, the code is essentially func2(9)()

Comment: Yes, you can also omit `func2Result`... maybe I should have done that instead, but I thought maybe seeing `()()` is also confusing `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`